# Reading huge CSV file with Spark

Tags: java, scala, csv, apache-spark

I have 27 GB gz csv file, that I am trying to read with Spark.
Our biggest node has 30 GB of memory.

When I am trying to read the file only one executors is loading the data (I am monitoring the memory and the network), the other 4 are stale.

After a while it crashes due to memory.

Is there a way to read this file in parallel?

```
Dataset<Row> result = sparkSession.read()
                .option("header","true")
                .option("escape", "\"")
                .option("multiLine","true")
                .format("csv")
                .load("s3a://csv-bucket");

result.repartition(10)

spark_conf:
 spark.executor.memoryOverhead: "512"
 spark.executor.cores: "5"

driver:
  memory: 10G

executor:
  instances: 5
  memory: 30G
```

Comment: `gz` files are not splittable and hence the read occurs on one executor. Once you read the `gz` file into a dataframe, you can repartition it.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala is right...  you have to repartition it to ensure uniform distribution of the data other wise OOM may occur or processing speed is slow.

Comment: I tried to repartition the data it fails before it gets to the repartition. I think the uncompressed data can't fit single machine

Comment: You can try the solution given in below URL,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638901/how-spark-read-a-large-file-petabyte-when-file-can-not-be-fit-in-sparks-main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to repartition the data when it comes to huge data

In spark unit of parallelism is partition

```
Dataset<Row> result = sparkSession.read()
                .option("header","true")
                .option("escape", "\"")
                .option("multiLine","true")
                .format("csv")
                .load("s3a://csv-bucket");



result.repartition(5 * 5 *3) ( number of executors i.e.5 * cores i.e. 5 * replicationfactor i.e. 2-3)  i.e. 25 might be working for you to ensure uniform disribution data.
```

**Cross check  how many number of records are there per partition** 
`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id
   yourcsvdataframe.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count.show()`

Example :

```
  val mycsvdata =
    """
      |rank,freq,Infinitiv,Unreg,Trans,"Präsens_ich","Präsens_du","Präsens_er, sie, es","Präteritum_ich","Partizip II","Konjunktiv II_ich","Imperativ Singular","Imperativ Plural",Hilfsverb
      |3,3796784,sein,"","",bin,bist,ist,war,gewesen,"wäre",sei,seid,sein
      |8,1618550,haben,"","",habe,hast,hat,hatte,gehabt,"hätte",habe,habt,haben
      |10,1379496,einen,"","",eine,einst,eint,einte,geeint,einte,eine,eint,haben
      |12,948246,werden,"","",werde,wirst,wird,wurde,geworden,"würde",werde,werdet,sein
    """.stripMargin.lines.toList.toDS
  val csvdf: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("header", true)
    .csv(mycsvdata)

  csvdf.show(false)
  println("all the 4 records are in single partition 0 ")

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id
  csvdf.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count.show()

  println( "now divide data... 4 records to 2 per partition")
  csvdf.repartition(2).groupBy(spark_partition_id).count.show()
```

Result :

```
 +----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+
|rank|freq   |Infinitiv|Unreg|Trans|Präsens_ich|Präsens_du|Präsens_er, sie, es|Präteritum_ich|Partizip II|Konjunktiv II_ich|Imperativ Singular|Imperativ Plural|Hilfsverb|
+----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+
|3   |3796784|sein     |null |null |bin        |bist      |ist                |war           |gewesen    |wäre             |sei               |seid            |sein     |
|8   |1618550|haben    |null |null |habe       |hast      |hat                |hatte         |gehabt     |hätte            |habe              |habt            |haben    |
|10  |1379496|einen    |null |null |eine       |einst     |eint               |einte         |geeint     |einte            |eine              |eint            |haben    |
|12  |948246 |werden   |null |null |werde      |wirst     |wird               |wurde         |geworden   |würde            |werde             |werdet          |sein     |
+----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+

all the 4 records are in single partition 0 
+--------------------+-----+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|                   0|    4|
+--------------------+-----+

now divide data... 4 records to 2 per partition
+--------------------+-----+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|                   1|    2|
|                   0|    2|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: I tried to repartition the data it fails before it gets to the repartition. I think the uncompressed data can't fit single machine

Comment: since gz is not splittable .. csvdf.repartition(200).write.parquet("/path/to/repartitioned/part/file") then process parquet also you may need to increase executor memory also..

Comment: I am getting this error: `ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 123950 ms` it retries and then fails

Comment: the reason reason/cause in the complete stack trace this is just a symptom